# jQuery appending to a dynamically created div

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jsplumb

Trying to add a save/load feature using JSON to a diagram that uses [jsPlumb](http://jsplumbtoolkit.com/demo/home/dom.html). The save feature works like a charm however the load feature is not able to replicate full initial saved state. That is, *the problem occurs when jQuery is trying to append to a freshly/dynamically created div.*

The jsfiddle has the following functionality:
I can add projects which are div containers. Inside these I can add tasks by clicking on the green projects.

http://jsfiddle.net/9yej6/1/

My saving code plugins everything into an array which then becomes a string (using JSON).

> ```
> $('#saveall').click(function(e) {
>     // Saving all of the projects' parameters
>     var projects = []
>     $(".project").each(function (idx, elem) {
>       var $elem = $(elem);
>       projects.push({
>         blockId: $elem.attr('id'),
>         positionX: parseInt($elem.css("left"), 10),
>         positionY: parseInt($elem.css("top"), 10)
>       });
>     });
>
>     // Saving all of the tasks' parameters
>     var tasks = []
>     $(".task").each(function (idx, elem) {
>       var $elem = $(elem);
>       tasks.push({
>         blockId: $elem.attr('id'),
>         parentId: $elem.parent().attr('id')
>       });
>     });
>
>     // Convert into string and copy to textarea
>     var flowChart = {};
>     flowChart.projects = projects;
>     flowChart.tasks = tasks;
>     var flowChartJson = JSON.stringify(flowChart);
>     $('#jsonOutput').val(flowChartJson);
> });
> ```

The load code does the same in reverse.

> ```
>   $('#loadall').click(function(e) {
>       // Delete everything from the container
>       $('#container').text("");
>
>       // Convert textarea string into JSON object
>       var flowChartJson = $('#jsonOutput').val();
>       var flowChart = JSON.parse(flowChartJson);
>
>       // Load all projects
>       var projects = flowChart.projects;
>       $.each(projects, function( index, elem ) {
>         addProject(elem.blockId);
>         repositionElement(elem.blockId, elem.positionX, elem.positionY)
>       });
>
>       // Try to load all tasks
>       var tasks = flowChart.tasks;
>       $.each(tasks, function( index, elem ) {
>         //Problem occurs here, I am unable to reference the created project
>         $(elem.parentId).text('This is a test');
>         addTask(elem.parentId, 0);
>       });   
>  });
> ```

Basically, what's not working is the `$(parentId).append(newState);` **line 75** in the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9yej6/1/), I can't seem to reference that div because it was just created using jquery ?

edit:
More specifically, I make use of these functions to create actual project and task `div`s

> ```
> function addProject(id) {  
> var newProject = $('<div>').attr('id', id).addClass('project').text(id);
>
>   $('#container').append(newProject);
>
>   jsPlumb.draggable(newProject, {
>     containment: 'parent'   }); 
> }
>
> function addTask(parentId, index) {
> var newState = $('<div>').attr('id', 'state' + index).addClass('task').text('task ' + index);
>
>   $(parentId).append(newState);
> }
> ```

Comment: There's no `append()` in the code you posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be:

```
$('#' + parentId).append(newState);
```

To search for an ID in a jQuery selector, you need the `#` prefix.

Comment: Thank you that did it, though I've modified another part of the code instead - I've added the `#` to the loading code `addTask('#' + elem.parentId, 0);` as initially the append code worked fine when just creating projects/tasks